# Migrating Files from Parse.com to our hosted parse server [image]

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, migration, parse-server

I have migrated files from Parse.com to my hosted parse server using "https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils" tool by applying "Option-2".

Now My problem is when I click on the image in my hosted parse server dashboard, it will show me message "File not found." and my url is like,

http://ip of my server:1337/parse/files/OE9gP1wrd2OT9avp3RBmt8zysmM25wRTMtDOxsfe/tfss-6ca44378-72fb-4ddf-aef2-11af0485b11b-profile-pic

If I upload new image from mobile aap, its working fine.

I have installed mongodb and migrated parse.com data to newly created database in mongodb.

I am not using any FileAdapter in my new created parse server.

Thanks in advance, kindly please look into this issue and help me that how can I display migrated images in our hosted parse server.

Comment: Where are you hosting your parse server?

Comment: I have hosted on linode server

Answer (score 0):

What is the http error you are seeing (404?)  Are you sure the error is "file not found"?  Maybe your server folder permission is set not set to public, so you can't publicly access the files (should be a 403 error).

You usually store the image files to a container (storage) that can be accessed via APIs like Amazon (AWS) or Microsoft Azure.   It's usually more efficient to keep you local server file storage small and have fast access speeds to your images.

You can find out how to setup an Amazon S3 bucket or Google Cloud Storage [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Configuring-File-Adapters#configuring-s3adapter).

You can find out how to setup an Azure Storage [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/?b=16.50) and connect it to your parse-server using this [adapter](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/parse-server-azure-storage).

I'm not sure about AWS, but Google and Azure gives you free credits if you sign up, and (at least for Azure) the storage aren't too expensive, so the free credits can last you a while...